# Get current node simpleType

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm using `XmlReader` to validate an XML file against an XSD and read each node for further validation.

In the XSD, some nodes rules are declared like this :

```
<xs:simpleType name="ShortValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

When reading a node, is there a way to retrieve the `simpleType` (or XSD type) of the current node declared in the XSD ?

Comment: If you're using a validating reader (one created with `XmlReaderSettings.ValidationType` set) then [`XmlReader.SchemaInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.schemainfo) should have everything you could want to know on the current node (in particular, `SchemaType.Name`). Disclaimer: never used, not tested.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert !! That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you post your comment in response ?

Comment: I wanted to expand it into a full ready-to-run answer, but even a basic example with schemas turns out to be quite involved, so this'll have to do. Feel free to edit in more if you think it's warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a validating reader (one created with [XmlReaderSettings.`ValidationType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationtype) set) then [`XmlReader.SchemaInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.schemainfo) should have everything you could want to know on the current node. In particular, the name of the schema type is in `SchemaInfo.SchemaType.Name`.